# Excel max value return

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this excel sheet

[image]

I want cell `H4` to show the date (column A) corresponding to the maximum value in column H.

In this case it should be 15/1/2016

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following formula:

```
=INDEX($A$6:$A$13,MATCH(MAX($H$6:$H$13),$H$6:$H$13,0))
```

You may need to format the cell as a date to display correctly.

[image]

Comment: I used the formula you suggested (with ctrl + shift + enter) but it is not working. It just shows an error message

Comment: I use excel 2003, if it matters

Comment: @ThomasD. What error is it showing?

Comment: "The formula you typed contains an error"... It's the translation, because i have greek office

Comment: I copy-pasted quite a few times both formulas you suggested and i paid attention to the brackets. 

Still it's not working   :-/

Answer (score 0):

1. Use MAX() to identify the maximum value in column H
2. Use MATCH() to identify which row in Column H contains that value.
3. Use INDEX() to return the value in column A that is in the row found in step 2.
4. Use TEXT() to format the result as a date.

If you have a "tie" for maximum value, then the one highest in the list will be used.

```
=TEXT(INDEX(A6:A13,MATCH(MAX(H6:H13),H6:H13,0),1),"MM/DD/YYYY")
```

I don't have enough reputation for my screenshot to show automatically, so in this example:

- A6:A13 contains dates
- H6:H13 are the values that you're looking through to find the max

And finally, take note of the MATCH() function. It's MATCH(lookup_value,lookup_array,match_type), and I set the match type to zero. This is important if the data that you're matching on is not sorted by ascending values. If the match type is omitted or set to one, then it will do approximate matching which is almost never what you want.

[image]